# Transform json in AWS-GLUE and upload in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

i came forward reading this amazon article about flattening a json file and uploading in redshift.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

My plan is to transform the json file and upload it in s3 then crawl the file again into the aws-glue to the data catalog and upload the data as tables in amazon redshift.

Now the problem with the code in 'Sample 3: Python code to transform the nested JSON and output it to ORC' shows some errors:

NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Not I am at lost because I am new to aws-glue and I need to upload json (they are nested arrays)in redshift.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
#from awsglue.transforms import Relationalize



# Begin variables to customize with your information
glue_source_database = "DATABASE"
glue_source_table = "TABLE_NAME"
glue_temp_storage = "s3://XXXXX"
glue_relationalize_output_s3_path = "s3://XXXXX"
dfc_root_table_name = "root" #default value is "roottable"
# End variables to customize with your information

glueContext = GlueContext(spark.sparkContext)
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = glue_source_table, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
dfc = Relationalize.apply(frame = datasource0, staging_path = glue_temp_storage, name = dfc_root_table_name, transformation_ctx = "dfc")
blogdata = dfc.select(dfc_root_table_name)
blogdataoutput = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = blogdata, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path}, format = "orc", transformation_ctx = "blogdataoutput")
```

Answer (score 0):

You create wrongly the `GlueContext`. Your code should look like

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
```

You can have a look at [Glue code examples from AWS](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/join_and_relationalize.py).

Comment: yes I check the link provided by @beni, in the code sample its mentioned as "glueContext = GlueContext(spark.sparkContext)".  Not sure how they got it working.  But as referred above, please change the glueContext object creation syntax, and it should work.

Comment: from pyspark.context import SparkContext --- this part is already part of the script so i didnt add it anymore furher

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate()) - --- i changed the glue context code and changed it to this way.. however, i am still having errors and says

An error occured while calling o87.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Job aborted..

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error? In the job history there's a link to CloudWatch logs for the job run.

Answer (score 0):

@beni

I had same issue following the guide as you do, correct spark context leads to another issue with writing **glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options**.

Checking the log, I saw a **null value error**. So adding **DropNullFields.apply** solved the issue

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

# Begin variables to customize with your information
glue_source_database = "database_name"
glue_source_table = "table_name"
glue_temp_storage = "s3://bucket/tmp"
glue_relationalize_output_s3_path = "s3://bucket/output"
dfc_root_table_name = "root"  # default value is "roottable"
# End variables to customize with your information

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = GlueContext(sc).spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=glue_source_database, table_name=glue_source_table,
                                                            transformation_ctx="datasource0")
dfc = Relationalize.apply(frame=datasource0, staging_path=glue_temp_storage, name=dfc_root_table_name,
                          transformation_ctx="dfc")
fb_data = dfc.select(dfc_root_table_name)
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame=fb_data, transformation_ctx="dropnullfields3")
fb_dataoutput = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=dropnullfields3, connection_type="s3",
                                                             connection_options={
                                                                 "path": glue_relationalize_output_s3_path},
                                                             format="orc", transformation_ctx="fb_dataoutput")

job.commit()
```

Hope this help!